# autofac wcf configured for WCF is not registered with the Autofac container

Tags: c#, wcf, autofac, unit-of-work

I am doing a project in WCF with DDD, Unit of Work and autofac.wcf and gives me the following error.

The service 'WebCode.Service.WCF.TablasMaestrasService,WebCode.Service.WCF' configured for WCF is not registered with the Autofac container.

Bootstrapper.cs

```cs
builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>();
builder.RegisterType<DatabaseFactory>().As<IDatabaseFactory>();
builder.RegisterType<SystemRuntimeCacheStorage>().As<ICacheStorage>();
builder
    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(PaisRepository).Assembly)
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();

builder
    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(PaisService).Assembly)
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();

IContainer container = builder.Build();

container.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();
container.Resolve<IDatabaseFactory>();
container.Resolve<ICacheStorage>();

AutofacHostFactory.Container = container;
```

TablasMaestrasService.svc

```
<%@ ServiceHost
    Language="C#"
    Debug="true"
    Service="WebCode.Service.WCF.TablasMaestrasService,WebCode.Service.WCF" 
    Factory="Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacServiceHostFactory, Autofac.Integration.Wcf"
    CodeBehind="TablasMaestrasService.cs" %>
```

TablasMaestrasService.cs

```cs
[ServiceContract]
public class TablasMaestrasService : ITablasMaestrasService
{
    private readonly IPaisService _paisService;

    public TablasMaestrasService(IPaisService paisService)
    {
        _paisService = paisService;
    }

    public List<PaisDto> GetPaises()
    {
        return = _paisService.GetAll();
    }
}
```

ITablasMaestrasService.cs

```cs
[ServiceContract]    
public interface ITablasMaestrasService
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<PaisDto> GetPaises();
}
```

that could be happening?
some help

Comment: It is not where the repository is called and validations are performed

Comment: I also think the `[ServiceContract]` attribute needs to be on the interface, not on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Register your service implementation:

```
builder.RegisterType<WebCode.Service.WCF.TablasMaestrasService>();
```

[Autofac documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/wcf.html)

Comment: you always need to register the service implementation, that's true. in this case, it needs to be registered as itself - `TablasMaestrasService` - because that's what the `.svc` file references via the `Service` attribute.

Comment: Adding the line gives me this error.
The service class of type TablasMaestrasService defines ServiceContract and inherits ServiceContract from the type ITablasMaestrasService. Contract inheritance can only be used between interface types. If a class is marked with the ServiceContractAttribute attribute, it must be the only type in the hierarchy with ServiceContractAttribute. Consider moving the ServiceContractAttribute in the type WebCode.Service.WCF.ITablasMaestrasService to a separate interface implemented by the type WebCode.Service.WCF.ITablasMaestrasService.

Comment: Error message is correct. You have to move [ServiceContract] attribute from service to interface ITablasMaestrasService. Also check if methods of that interface have [OperationContract] attribute.

Comment: Remove [ServiceContract] from TablasMaestrasService. It should be only on interface.